# Custom gradle task gets executed even during sync

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I am sure this is something very dumb mistake, but I need your help since I am not a gradle expert.

**TASK:**
read versionCode from file add +1 to it and save it back.

```
task executeOrderSixtySix {
def versionPropsFile = file('versionCodes.properties')
if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def versionNumber = versionProps['DEV_VERSION'].toInteger() + 1
    versionProps['DEV_VERSION'] = versionNumber.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    //     'assembleDebug'

} else {
    throw new GradleException("Nyeeeh on versionCodes.properties!")
}}
```

So when I have to do an internal drop I would like to run this task first, increase the devVersion number by 1 and then run the 'assemble' task to build all artifacts.

**PROBLEM:**
This task executes itself, even if I just sync the cradle file causing increased versionCode all the time.

I don't want to increase the versionCode during sync, development build only just for QAdrop, when I also have to assemble every APK.

Could you please help me out and tell me why is this task getting called/executed and who can I prevent it?

Comment: as a temp solution I added this     if ('executeOrderSixtySix' in gradle.startParameter.taskNames) {
......} , which works fine but I do believe there should be a better way out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `doLast` block inside of your task block. build.gradle file is a configuration script so it reads as declare the task when on configuration and declare the action on the execution.

> Anything done in the task either before or after the doLast block would be run during configuration time. The code in the doLast block itself runs at execution time.

```
task executeOrderSixtySix {
    doLast {
        def versionPropsFile = file('versionCodes.properties')
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

            def versionNumber = versionProps['DEV_VERSION'].toInteger() + 1
            versionProps['DEV_VERSION'] = versionNumber.toString()
            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

            //     'assembleDebug'

        } else {
            throw new GradleException("Nyeeeh on versionCodes.properties!")
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://www.oreilly.com/learning/write-your-own-custom-tasks-in-gradle

Comment: Thanks, will try. Who can I call basic build tasks from here? Such as assembleDebug?

Comment: you can use dependsOn to define the dependency of this task.  If you want to run this after the assembleDebug then you can write `task executeOrderSixtySix(dependsOn: assembleDebug)`

Comment: I would like to run before, so this task increase the versionCode number and assembleDebug will pick the new number from the file!

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks

I haven't tried but try `assembleDebug.shouldRunAfter executeOrderSixtySix`

Comment: as far as I know that's only says if should only run after, but not going to execute the task itself. If they are running together gradle will make sure A runs after B; Anyway, I do appreciate your help, it would be great if we could solve this together ! (Will be back soon)